# Use SR 830 lock-in amplifier to detect the second harmonic component with respect to an external reference

Tags: amplifier, signal

I have a sine wave external reference at frequency f0, which is connected to BNC REF IN. The response signal is fed into input BNC A/I, I want to detect the second harmonic component in the input signal at 2*f0. Is there any simple way for this? I guess I may need a frequency synthesizer. Thank you.

Comment: Did you read the manual?

Comment: Look in the SR830 manual under harmonic detection.

Comment: Can't you just set it to 2nd harmonic? Theres a button to select which harmonic you want on the front panel. Or does that not work with an external reference frequency?

Comment: Yes, you can never underestimate how stupid one can sometimes be. The button indeed also works with an external reference. I thought it works with the internal one only before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe put a high pass filter in to filter out the first frequency component. Then it would have to lock-in to the harmonic. Don't know if this would actually work in your application.

Most lock in amplfiiers have a frequency to set to lock into, and you may be able to set it to the harmonic, and it would lock in on that.

Comment: Thanks. I was very stupid. The harmonic selection also works w.r.t an external reference. I was not aware of that before. I just need to feed a reference with at least 500mVpp amplitude for it to lock on.